# Flutter url_launcher crashes opening apple maps on ios

Tags: ios, flutter

I've got a simple flutter app which is using maps_launcher which in turn uses url_launcher

```
  url_launcher: ^6.1.12
  maps_launcher: ^2.2.0
```

On the ios simulator, and ios devices, Maps launcher sends a formatted query to url_launcher and breaks in this function:

```
Future<bool> openUrlInSafariViewController(String arg_url) async {
    final BasicMessageChannel<Object?> channel = BasicMessageChannel<Object?>(
        'dev.flutter.pigeon.UrlLauncherApi.openUrlInSafariViewController',
        codec,
        binaryMessenger: _binaryMessenger);
    final List<Object?>? replyList =
        await channel.send(<Object?>[arg_url]) as List<Object?>?;
    if (replyList == null) {
      throw PlatformException(
        code: 'channel-error',
        message: 'Unable to establish connection on channel.',
      );
    } else if (replyList.length > 1) { //THIS IS WHERE THE EXCEPTION IS TRIGGERED
      throw PlatformException(
        code: replyList[0]! as String,
        message: replyList[1] as String?,
        details: replyList[2],
      );
    } else if (replyList[0] == null) {
      throw PlatformException(
        code: 'null-error',
        message: 'Host platform returned null value for non-null return value.',
      );
    } else {
      return (replyList[0] as bool?)!;
    }
  }
```

The link that gets sent works and apple maps is successfully opened - but the app crashes because replyList has error text such as

```
PlatformException (PlatformException(Error, Error while launching https://maps.apple.com/?q=Merivale+Lane+Theatre+Rangi+Ruru+Girls+School+Merivale+Lane+off+Rossall+Street+, null, null))
```

The easy solution is to fork url_launcher and ignore the errors but I'd rather understand where I'm going wrong.

Elsewhere I'm using url_launcher directly and it's fine. There's something about the channel object? or the map?

Any ideas?